# How do I find out where a call to my webservice (.net asmx) came from?

Tags: .net, security, web-services

From within a webmethod (.net asmx file) - is it possible to determine from where the call to the webmethod came?

Thank you

Comment: Define `where`. Is it the client IP calling the WebMethod you are looking for?

Comment: anything really; ip address, name of page etc. I'd like some rich information about the calls to my webservice, other than it's been called X times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this :

```
httpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_members%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

To get this host IP adress. but if by where you mean a place, , you can't.

Comment: Well, you could if you call a GeoIP WebService with the desired IP, and then that would convert it to the actual place of the call (see Proxy, ISP or Host Locations)

Comment: cool this should work, the HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer is what I was looking for.